# Не работает dump-autoload в композиторе!

Tags: php, composer, namespace

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
{
    "name": "skr-x/mvc_php",
    "description": "MVC PHP",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Components\\": "components/",
            "Controllers\\": "controllers/",
            "Models\\": "models/",
            "Github\\": "github/",
            "Core\\": "core/",
            "Src\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу обновить композеру пути по его .json файлу, но файлы композера не обновляются => я не имею возможности пользоваться "src\" неймспейсом, все остальные в строю, раньше их добавлял в композер так:
1. Добавлял новые неймспейсы и роуты к ним в .jsonе композитора.
2. Composer dump-autoload -o / Composer dump-autoload /  Composer dumpautoload находясь в папке проекта.
3. Новые неймспейсы были готовы к работе.

Что делать? Может я задел что и переустановить композитора? Или было у кого такое? Как я понял зависает все когда я прошу сделать его дамп в консоли, тк ввроде как у меня было "Generated files", а сейчас только "generating files", видимо он эту процедуру закончить не может.

EDIT:

Я обновил композер и получил вывод в терминале - "d:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\localhost>composer dump-autoload -o
Generated optimized autoload files containing 16 classes", но хоть и написано что файлы были сгенерированы - файлы композера не обновились.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без понятия что это, но вроде когда делаю дампы в PHPSTORM то все работает.